# Statement: with and tarfile

Tags: python

I try to use `with` statement and tarfile module...

```
with tarfile.open('/dir/dir/dir.tar.gz', 'w:gz') as fl:
    fl.add('/dir/dir/dir/', arcname = '/')
```

So it shows the next:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
AttributeError: 'TarFile' object has no attribute '__exit__'
```

I try to create tar.gz file and close it using statement is, but it show an error. What is the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [contextlib.closing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing), e.g.:

```
from contextlib import closing
with closing(tarfile.open('/dir/dir/dir.tar.gz', 'w:gz')) as fl:
    fl.add('/dir/dir/dir/', arcname = '/')
```

From docs:

> Even if an error occurs, `page.close()` will be called when the with block is exited.

`contextlib.closing` is available since Python 2.5 (or maybe even earlier...).

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you don't have a sufficiently new versions of the Python standard libraries.  Looking at [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html) which says:

- ***New in version 2.7: Added support for the context manager protocol.***

Incidentally those docs should be your first recourse when you encounter behavior you don't understand with anything in the Python standard libraries.  Reading that page, in particular would answer your question if you understood that the whole "context management" system (object protocol) is relatively new and accessed via the perversely search hostile `with` keyword in Python.

This object protocol implements some useful implicit semantics around closing files, releasing locks and other clean-up and resource management concerns ... even in the face of exceptions.  Fundamentally this is semantic sugar around `try:`...`finally:` ... with some features that you can add to your classes to leverage that support.

To understand that further you would best read: [with Statement Context Managers](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=context%20manager#with-statement-context-managers).

Answer (score 2):

Your error message is incorrectly copied. It shoulod read `AttributeError: 'TarFile' object has no attribute '__exit__'`.

You are evidently using a Python version earlier than 2.7, which added support for the "context manager" protocol (which is necessary for using the `with` statement) to the `tarfile` module.

Two options for you:

(1) upgrade to 2.7 **BUT** do notice that as documented the support is not complete: """A TarFile object can be used as a context manager in a with statement. It will automatically be closed when the block is completed. Please note that in the event of an exception an archive opened for writing will not be finalized; only the internally used file object will be closed.

(2) stay on 2.6 or whatever and do it "manually" with try/except/finally.